# Azure Function POST interpreted as GET when using http rather than https

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions .NET Core 3.1 endpoint to which I am sending a POST command from Postman.  When I send a request to my endpoint using **https** (SSL), everything is normal.  When I hit the same endpoint using **http**, the Method of the incoming HttpRequest is "GET" rather than "POST".  I have nothing fancy in the host.json file and nothing else unusual about this function app other than the fact that my function can take either GET or POST methods.  Here is my host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

Any my function:

```
[FunctionName("GraphQL")]
public IActionResult Get
(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "graphql")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log
)
{
    // ... req.Method === "GET" here when under only http, even when a POST
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that probably your HTTP request sent via http is receiving a 302 response and therefore redirecting it.

When redirecting it will not redirect as a POST but as a GET and you function will treat it as a GET.

On your Azure Function App settings / Custom Domains try setting HTTPS only to true to see if it will fix the issue.

Comment: That's a really excellent suggestion.  Unfortunately when I went to try this, before doing anything, the problem no longer manifests.  Sheesh!  Well thanks anyway Carlos, that probably would have worked so I'll mark it as the answer.